# Updating all Meteor packages to latest versions

Tags: meteor

I'm developing a Meteor app that isn't yet in production, so I can afford to move quickly when adopting new package versions (useraccounts had a significant version bump a few hours after I'd integrated it, for instance.) This was what I thought `meteor update` was meant to accomplish. Yet when I run:

`meteor update`

from my project, I'm told that packages were updated but .meteor/versions remains unchanged.

I can upgrade the package by running `meteor add someone:package@whatever`, but this just shuffles the version dependency from .meteor/versions to .meteor/packages even though it seems to do the upgrade. I'm happy to lock versions down when I go to production, but it seems like in development I should be able to use the update command, especially as `meteor list` indicates that as a next step.

I've managed to upgrade all my packages by removing .meteor/versions and .meteor/local and running `meteor update`, but this seems messy.

I also found [this issue](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/3393) but it was closed. Should it be reopened or should I open a new issue? I understand how semver works, but I think the issue is that Meteor isn't writing its constraint solver results to .meteor/versions so doesn't realize that package updates have been applied. Is that accurate or am I just misunderstanding something?

Comment: Could you post up the complete output of `meteor list`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For the time being it looks like that you have 2 options for packages which have updates you wish to use:

1. remove and add the package of concern via `meteor remove provider:package_name` and `meteor add provider:package_name`
2. update packages with their specific version manually via `meteor add provider:package_name@X.X.X`

[Meteor won't update packages unless you remove and add them #2500](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2500)

Comment: after `meteor update package-xyz` don't you have to do something to make it permanent across the next restart? Edit config?

Answer (score 37):

now u can simply do

```
meteor update --all-packages
```

Answer (score 28):

Expanding on previous answers, you can update all packages with this:

```
grep -ve '^#' .meteor/packages | xargs meteor update
```

Comment: this is the correct answer to the question posted. thank you

Answer (score 14):

You can also use `meteor update provider:package_name`

Answer (score 13):

Easiest way is to delete the contents of .meteor/versions and then save. Next time you run meteor it will update all packages to the latest version.

Comment: This is the most effective and easiest way to do it as I find.

Answer (score 2):

Just tiny addition to @Meteorpoly answer:

You can also edit package version in .meteor/versions file manually and meteor will pick it up on next/current run

Answer (score 2):

From Meteor docs: `meteor update --packages-only`

This command will update all the packages which are not built locally, has an update available and is also compatible with the meteor version you are using.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that now

```
meteor update
```

is enough to update all packages

Answer (score 0):

lets assume you wish to keep your meteor at your current release then issue

```
meteor --release foo    update --all-packages
```

where foo   indicates your current meteor release ... you can identify your release by looking at file

```
cat .meteor/release
```

which for me has content of

```
METEOR@1.10.2
```

so my current meteor release is `1.10.2` ... to leave alone my current meteor release yet upgrade all packages to match my release `1.10.2` then command is

```
meteor --release 1.10.2    update --all-packages
```

alternatively if you wish to fully upgrade to both latest meteor release AND that release's package upgrades then issue

```
meteor update --all-packages
```

Answer (score -1):

I used [packagecheck](https://www.npmjs.com/package/packagecheck). It analyzed the project, showed me available updates and assisted the general update.

```
$ npm install -g packagecheck
$ packagecheck
```