# Meteor 1.3 node build: doesn't work anymore with React

Tags: meteor

With 1.2.*, I used to build my staging/production bundles with `meteor build`, then moving into ./bundle/programs/server and `npm install` there.

I do the same thing with 1.3 version but now I have error message on trying to run bundle main file with node:

```
WARNING: npm peer requirements not installed:
 - react@0.14.x not installed.
 - react-addons-pure-render-mixin@0.14.x not installed.

Read more about installing npm peer dependencies:
http://guide.meteor.com/using-packages.html#peer-npm-dependencies


/var/www/builds/1459320997/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/future.js:267
                                            throw(ex);
                                                  ^
Error: Can't find npm module 'react'. Did you forget to call 'Npm.depends' in package.js within the 'modules-runtime' package?
```

I use `react-meteor-data` meteor package.

However, I already have `"react": "^0.14.8",` and `"react-addons-linked-state-mixin": "^0.14.8",` in my package.json and of course installed it with `npm install ... --save` and it is working fine on development environment when I use `meteor` command.

Any additional actions needed to run it? Did they change how meteor package should be build for production and didn't changed their docs? (because I don't see any changes in docs concerning `meteor build` so far.

Update: I tried to manually `npm install` these packages into `./bundle/program/server`. Now they consequentially requires packages already listed in my package.json. I suppose Meteor just ignore this file on bundle. Will try to add a bug in their tracker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used Meteor 1.2 to build new 1.3 code so it is the issue. It happened because currently I build on the server that had another Meteor version.

Answer (score 0):

I used answer from another Stackoverflow user (Ian) [Updating all Meteor packages to latest versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28612459/updating-all-meteor-packages-to-latest-versions)

Easiest way is to delete the contents of .meteor/versions and then save

Comment: It resolves another issue as far as I see. Npm modules have nothing common with ./meteor/versions